# Properly Establishing an ApplicationEndpoint in UCMA 3.0

Tags: proxy, ucma, lync-2010

I've been struggling with getting an application endpoint working on UCMA 3.0. I am trying to run an application on a server separate from the Lync server which uses a registered ApplicationEndpoint to monitor presence and act as a bot which can send other users messages. I used to have my code working with a UserEndpoint (which was fine for monitoring presence), but did not have the capabilities to send IMs to other Lync users.

After searching the web, I'm finally at the point where I'm getting this error when running my code:

System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=An ApplicationEndpoint can be registered only if proxy and Multual Tls have been specified.
  Source=Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.ApplicationEndpoint..ctor(CollaborationPlatform platform, ApplicationEndpointSettings settings)
       at Waldo.endpointHelper.CreateApplicationEndpoint(ApplicationEndpointSettings applicationEndpointSettings) in C:\Users\l1m5\Desktop\waldoproject\trunk\WaldoSoln\waldoGrabPresence\endpointHelper.cs:line 117
       at Waldo.endpointHelper.CreateEstablishedApplicationEndpoint(String endpointFriendlyName) in C:\Users\l1m5\Desktop\waldoproject\trunk\WaldoSoln\waldoGrabPresence\endpointHelper.cs:line 228
       at Waldo.waldoGrabPresence.Run() in C:\Users\l1m5\Desktop\waldoproject\trunk\WaldoSoln\waldoGrabPresence\waldoGrabPresence.cs:line 60
       at Waldo.waldoGrabPresence.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\l1m5\Desktop\waldoproject\trunk\WaldoSoln\waldoGrabPresence\waldoGrabPresence.cs:line 42
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

After some searching, I followed the instructions here: http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/michael_greenlee/archive/2009/03/21/installing-a-certificate-for-ucma-v2-0-applications.aspx to import a certificate onto the server that I'm trying to run the application on, but to no avail.

So at this point, I think that there must be something wrong with how I'm setting up the ApplicationEndpointSettings, CollaberationPlatform or ApplicationEndpoint objects. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
ApplicationEndpointSettings settings = new ApplicationEndpointSettings(_ownerURIPrompt, _serverFQDNPrompt, _trustedPortPrompt);

ServerPlatformSettings settings = new ServerPlatformSettings(null, _serverFQDNPrompt, _trustedPortPrompt, _trustedApplicationGRUU);

_collabPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(settings); 

_applicationEndpoint = new ApplicationEndpoint(_collabPlatform, applicationEndpointSettings);
```

Does anyone see any problems with what I'm doing? Or, better yet, does anyone know of a blog that walks you through establishing an application endpoint in the situation I'm in? I work really well with tutorials or samples, but have not found one that seems to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure to get a certificate in Lync is very different than OCS2007, and much easier.  The link you posted is for UCMA2, and OCS, I believe.  In Lync, it's basically two powershell statements.

1) Request-CSCertificate -Action new -Type default -CA  -Verbose

2) Save the results of that statement, take the thumbprint, use it as the parameter to:
Set-CsCertificate -Type Default -Thumbprint XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

[Installing UCMA 3.0 and Creating a Lync Server 2010 Trusted Application Pool](http://dotnetslackers.com/XML/re-380699_Installing_UCMA_3_0_and_Creating_a_Lync_Server_2010_Trusted_Application_Pool.aspx)

Comment: Here's an updated link for the article referenced above: http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/09/15/installing-ucma-3-0-and-creating-a-lync-server-2010-trusted-application-pool/

Answer (score 1):

use powershell to provision a trusted application endpoint. The command to explore is new-trustedapplicationendpoint. The error you are getting is due to no trusted endpoint being registered, even though you may have your trusted application registered, it needs an endpoint to work and that endpoint must be first registered before you provision the platform.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK CHM file should be your friend here! [This section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg437205.aspx) is about app activation and provisioning

Answer (score 0):

Pass the certificate to the `ServerPlatformSettings` object, then it works. I had the similar problem, and the problem is resolved after using the `ServerPlatformSettings(string applicationUserAgent, string localhost, int port, string gruu, string certificateIssuerName, byte[] certificateSerialNumber)` constructor for the `ServerPlatformSettings`.